# QGIS connect two branches of polygon and keep a ring inside

Tags: qgis, geometry, ring

I use QGIS 3.16, my sample is a polygon showed below:
[image]

As the result I would like to connect those two "branches" and keep an ring inside. I'm not sure which tool should I use to do this. I'd like to avoid adding second object. Actually I'm using vertex editor tool, but then I have additional line which I checked in the red rectangle on the picture below:
[image]

Comment: Overlapping/touching itself will mostly lead to faulty geometries. I suggest you add a real ring to the polygon instead of doing this. See the advanced digitizing toolbar.

Comment: @Erik i dont want to touch, i want to stick them to avoid that line between those parts. To add ring a have to make two steps; first is to fill whole area inside and second draw a ring. The problem is that after first step i lose the border of my polygon inside.

Answer (score 6):

1. Draw a new polygon covering the gap with some overlap with the old one
2. Select this and your old one
3. "Merge selected features"

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, that solution i knew, but maybe there is a way to do it without drawing additional object. The sample in my question was simple, but real usage is a way more complicated when using additional object ;)

Comment: I would just use this "add a bridge and merge". Another option would be to convert the polygon into linestring. Then it would be possible to cut the ring, remove sections from both ends of the branch, digitize connecting lines, and convert back to polygon. Editing the polygon directly is probably not possible with standard tools because at some stage of editing the polygon would be invalid because of self-intersection.

Answer (score 5):

@Bera's answer is cleaner as the risk of invalid geometry is greatly reduced....  if you don't want to create a 2nd object, you can achieve the task by applying a buffer of 0 on your self-touching polygon, either as a new layer or in-place.

1. using the vertex tool, design the polygon with its hole as you are doing. Ensure there is only a line in common (no gap, no overlap).
2. call the buffer tool, specify a distance of 0
3. the result will be a single polygon with an inner ring

[image]

**edit** Thanks to @J.R. comment, you can also opt to do the update in place by enabling "edit feature in place" (yellow square and pen icon at the top of the procession toolbox)

[image]

Comment: If you use the "edit feature in place" (yellow square and pen icon at the top of the procession toolbox) and select the polygon it won't create a new layer but will directly modify the polygon

Comment: @J.R awesome! I personally tend to keep copies at every step so if something happens I won't loose everything

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if QGIS allows to make edits that yield non-valid geometries, even temporarily.

**EDIT**

It is possible to make the required invalid edit with the vertex editor tool and QGIS does also have on option to update the geometry in-place without creating a new layer. The following OpenJUMP recipe performs the same task.

With OpenJUMP the task is rather simple.

[image]

Set program to allow invalid edits.

[image]

Original geometry

[image]

Add six new vertices

[image]

Drag two vertices to create an invalid polygon with the desired shape

[image]

Make the geometry valid

[image]

The result